# Zipping lists in python

Tags: python, list, zip

Let's say I have two lists:

```
["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]
```

I have to get output like this:

```
["aadd", "bbee", "ccffg"]
```

Zipping came in my mind, but I think it's a little more advanced than that, so I have really no idea, what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is slightly more complex than just `zip()`, but only just. Just add the item pairs together after zipping:

```
>>> [a+b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
['aadd', 'bbee', 'ccffg']
```

Where `list1` and `list2` are your lists.

This works because `zip()` returns an object made up of a series of tuples, which contain corresponding elements from the two iterables. Therefore to concatenate these items we just add them together each time, creating a new list.

Comment: I'd also recommend changing "a+b for a, b" to " ''.join(elem) for elem" to allow for cleaner expansion.

Comment: @AMacK That _would_ be better for bigger iterable amounts, but here the OP specifically said **2** iterables, so I will leave as it as it is for now unless the OP requests otherwise.

Comment: @AlexThorton Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this `map` version in. List comprehensions are more Pythonic, but here's an alternate.

```
>>> list1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
>>> list2 = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]
>>> map("".join, zip(list1, list2))
['aadd', 'bbee', 'ccffg']
```

You can even create a generator out of this one.

```
>>> from itertools import izip, imap
>>> final = imap("".join, izip(list1, list2))
>>> next(final)
'aadd'
>>> next(final)
'bbee'
```

Here are some timing results for the three different solutions. (The generator one beats everyone)

```
>>> timeit('[a+b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]', 'list1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]*100; list2 = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]*100', number=10000)
0.4470004917966719
>>> timeit('map("".join, zip(list1, list2))', 'list1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]*100; list2 = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]*100', number=10000)
0.43502864982517053
>>> timeit('imap("".join, izip(list1, list2))', 'from itertools import imap, izip; list1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]*100; list2 = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]*100', number=10000)
0.011020268755800089
>>> timeit('[a+b for a, b in izip(list1, list2)]', 'from itertools import izip; list1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]*100; list2 = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]*100', number=10000)
0.32172862839627214
>>> timeit('map(lambda x,y: x + y, list1, list2)', 'list1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]*100; list2 = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]*100', number=10000)
0.5423113458890612
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension in combination with zip will work; first zip them to pairs, then append the pairs individually using the comprehension.

```py
>>> list_a=["aa", "bb", "cc"]
>>> list_b=["dd", "ee", "ffg"]

# Using zip will pair the strings up in tuples
>>> zip(list_a, list_b)
[('aa', 'dd'), ('bb', 'ee'), ('cc', 'ffg')]

# ...so we just append them pair wise using a comprehension
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip(list_a, list_b)]
['aadd', 'bbee', 'ccffg']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=["aa", "bb", "cc"]
l2=["dd", "ee", "ffg"]
print [i+j for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Output:

```
['aadd', 'bbee', 'ccffg']
```

Access 2 list elements using zip and concatenate them in list comprehension

Comment: Well, your comprehension matches the desired result, but your sample output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you have two lists, and you need to perform the same operation ( concatenation ) between two elements at the same  index position.

A map function can take elements from lists and perform the required function

```
list_a = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
list_b = ["dd", "ee", "ffg"]

result = map(lambda x,y: x + y, list_a, list_b)
```